# Dynamically created parameter arguments for PowerShell's Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

Long story short, I'm trying to dynamically use a parameter `-Directory` or `-File` in PowerShell's `Get-ChildItem`. Guess what? I'm unable to.

Here's the deal (note: pseudo-code):

```
Param(
    [string]$filter = $(throw "Error: name"),
    [string]$type = $(throw "error: file or directory")
)

if( $type -eq "file" ) {
    $mode = '-File'
}
elseif( $type -eq "directory" ) {
    $mode = '-Directory'
}

Function Find_Plugin_folder {
    Write-Host "look for: '$($filter)'"
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Get-Content servers.txt ) -ScriptBlock {
        (Get-ChildItem -Path "z:\www" -Depth 5 $Using:mode -Filter $Using:filter -Recurse ) | %{$_.FullName}
    } -ThrottleLimit 80 
}

Find_Plugin_folder
```

`$Using:mode` is where it throws an error, either:

```
PS C:\Users\janreilink> v:\test.ps1 vevida-optimizer file
look for: 'vevida-optimizer'
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-File'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : webserver-01.example.net
```

Or

```
PS C:\Users\janreilink> v:\test.ps1 vevida-optimizer directory
look for: 'vevida-optimizer'
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-Directory'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : webserver-01.example.net
```

I've been reading about Dynamic Parameter sets all afternoon, but can't wrap my head around it yet. Any points are much (much, much) appreciated.

Comment: Another way might be to create the scriptblock from a string. `$scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [`splatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) for this instead. Start by creating a hashtable with some or all of the parameters you want to pass:

```
$dynamicArgs = @{}

if( $type -eq "file" ) {
    $dynamicArgs['File'] = $true
}
elseif( $type -eq "directory" ) {
    $dynamicArgs['Directory'] = $true
}
```

Then, inside `Invoke-Command`, prefix the variable name with `@` to indicate that you want to "splat" the arguments:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "z:\www" -Depth 5 @Using:dynamicArgs -Filter $Using:filter -Recurse
```

If the splatting table contains the key `File` with a value of `$true`, it's the equivalent of adding `-File:$true` on the command line, and vice versa for the `Directory` argument

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks. Answer marked as answer.